# SetTimout function that changes text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, textbox, settimeout

This is my second day of doing anything at all with javascript so I am a complete beginner. As the title states, I just want to change the text value of a textbox using the settimeout function. I have searched the internet and have come to a dead end. This is what I have so far,

```
    putftp.onclick = function () {
    var Text = document.getElementById("TextBox");


    function firsttext() {
       document.getElementbyID("TextBox").innerHTML = "This is the first test.";
       setTimeout("secondtest()",3000);
    }
    function secondtest() {
        document.getElementById("TextBox").innerHTML = "This is the second test.";
        setTimeout("thirdtest()",5000);
    }
   function thirdtest() {
        document.getElementById("TextBox").innerHTML = "This is the last test.";
    }
};
```

Im not sure if Im using the correct format, or if Im even anywhere close to being correct. Im pretty sure everything is ok except for the document.getElementbyID("textbox").innerHTML part. I would think something there would be changed, but its only my second day so I really could be clueless about this whole issue. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: For all the people who answered, `innerHTML` will not change the value of the text box >_>. its `.value = 'text'`

Comment: @f0x thanks, noticed that when building a test case. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the text once 3 seconds after the button click, have this:

```
putftp.onclick = function () {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       document.getElementById("TextBox").value = "This is the first test.";
    }, 3000);
};
```

You have two errors in your orignal code which I fixed for you:

1. Assuming `TextBox` is a text box, you need to assign its `value` property, not `innerHTML`.
2. The correct name is `getElementById` and not `getElementbyID`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

To change it again two seconds later, you can add "nested" timer:

```
putftp.onclick = function () {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       document.getElementById("TextBox").value = "This is the first test.";
       window.setTimeout(function() {
           document.getElementById("TextBox").value= "This is the second test.";
        }, 2000);
    }, 3000);
};
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/XcGpg/).

Comment: Sure thing that's what we're here for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The obvious problem with the code you've posted is that you haven't called `firsttest()`-function. Thus the first call to setTimeout is never being made. Furthermore, you could enhance your script by just passing the functions themselves, like so: `setTimeout(secondtest, 3000);`

Secondly, since you've already gotten the element once, why not shorten the code by cutting some of the getElementById:s out.

```
putftp.onclick = function () {
    var Text = document.getElementById("TextBox");

    function firsttext() {
        Text.innerHTML = "This is the first test.";
        setTimeout(secondtest, 3000);
    }
    function secondtest() {
         Text.innerHTML = "This is the second test.";
         setTimeout(thirdtest, 5000);
    }
    function thirdtest() {
         Text.innerHTML = "This is the last test.";
    }

    firsttext();
};
```

Comment: +1 for more teaching me to call the first function. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

The functions are not defined when executed, because passing a string causes it to run in the global scope. The functions are only defined inside the `onclick` handler.

You should just pass the function itself, and never pass strings. Also, why not actually use the `Text` variable? And you should start the process by executing the first function.

As a side note, your naming of `text` and `test` is not a very good one; it is easily misread.

```
putftp.onclick = function () {
    var Text = document.getElementById("TextBox");

    firsttext(); // start process

    function firsttext() {
       Text.innerHTML = "This is the first test.";
       setTimeout(secondtest, 3000);
    }

    function secondtest() {
        Text.innerHTML = "This is the second test.";
        setTimeout(thirdtest, 5000);
    }

    function thirdtest() {
        Text.innerHTML = "This is the last test.";
    }
};
```